# ios array crash multithreading issue, thread-saftety

Tags: ios, thread-safety, crash-reports

I'm analyzing a crash report and have come across an exception that may be due to a race-condition (my best guess).

Crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[9]
0    CoreFoundation       
__exceptionPreprocess + 132
2    CoreFoundation    
-[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 412
3    CoreFoundation    
-[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:] + 464
```

The most likely culprit is this from my code.  Since the array should never contain a nil value, my guess is a possible race condition, since this line runs on a repeating timer, and the batches array is updated with location-based requested also coming in regularly elsewhere.

```
NSArray *batchesCopy = [self.batches copy];
```

My question is what is the best way to protect against these race conditions?  Is there a thread-safe way to do an array copy or array edit in general?   For instance a mutex lock or maybe use the "atomic" option on the property?

Answer (score 1):

There is language level locking :

```
@synchronized(self){
    //array operations
}
```

Comment: Is one use around the "copy" function above effective, or does it require putting it around all uses?

Comment: You must put it around all the uses you want to synchronise.

Answer (score 0):

One way is the lockless approach, where you have a designated thread that is the only thread that ever reads or changes that object's value.  You can either use an existing serial thread (most commonly the main thread as it's already there and there are many easy ways to get code run on it) or keep a custom serial thread just for that object or class of object. The style is that whenever you need to interact with that thing you schedule a block on the designated thread that reads or writes the data and does the resulting work based on the new value. This way avoids deadlocks and spinlocks, and can be faster, but it can be more code.

Comment: The two threads are from an NSTimer, called as often as every several seconds.  The second is from CLLocation delegate updates.  They both access the same array.  Can you describe how I might synchronize the threads on these two types?